# How can I umount /dev/sda1 partition in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, diskmanagement, fdisk

I have a Ubuntu VM which has an unmanaged OS disk associated with it.

I want to shrink my OS disk of size 50 GB to 40 GB.
However, when i try to unmount /dev/sda1 partition it tell me

> umount: /mnt: device is busy.
>           (In some cases useful info about processes that use
>            the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))

Therefore, i am unable to unmount it and then shrink it. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: make sure no process has file handles from the partition open. you can use `lsof` to check for open files.

Comment: Use lsblk to see the mountpoint on /dev/sda1 (apparently /mnt). And do **fuser -vM /mnt** to see processes.

Comment: What's the output of `mount` ?

Comment: needs details but i think after 2 years its already gone

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your disk `/dev/sda1` is mounted. So the best you can do is to boot from live CD and then do the operations you want to do. When boot from live CD `/dev/sda1` will not be mounted.

Of course you can start to search for processes which keep open files in this filesystem. But this can take a lot of time.

Comment: The error message states that the partition is mounted in `/mnt`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, clarified

Comment: How can I boot my Virtual machine from live CD? Can you suggest me any article.

Comment: @SameerKeluskar, what is your hypervisor?